# AngularJs watch angular.element

Tags: angularjs, spring, jsp

I'm trying to integrate AngularJs into a legacy Spring MVC application because there is lots of spaghetti javascript code (a huge mess!) to hide / show html elements based on conditions etc.

It uses jsp and lots of custom jsp tags and because the way it is written I'm hesitant to mess with the jsp tags themselves.

I'm trying to do is read the values of the spring input into angular scope and once I have it then can use angular to hide / show stuff.

Assume that my html is something like this

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="FooCtrl">
    Backbone <input type="radio" name="yes" value="Backbone"/>
    Angular <input type="radio" name="yes" value="Angular" />
</div>
```

I'm able to read these elements into Angular's scope like this

```
$scope.elements = angular.element("input[name='yes']");
```

But change to the value of these elements are not getting triggered or watched by Angular.

Ideally when the radio button gets checked I would like the model to change. How can I do this?

Thank you in advance.

Here is plnkr with the basic setup.
http://plnkr.co/edit/CRPBFF9FaGivBRa8OSdZ?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing is that in your controller you had:

```
$scope.$watch('$scope.elements',function(newValue){
  console.log(newValue);
},true);
```

It should be `'elements'` rather than `'$scope.elements'`. I'm not quite sure if a $watch or $watchCollection is going to be your best bet here. I tried it but was having issues.

Here is another idea:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('FooCtrl', function($scope){
$scope.message = "hi";
$scope.elements = angular.element("input[name='yes']");

angular.element("input[name='yes']").bind("input change", function(e) {
    console.log(e);
  });
```

});